# Calculate Relative Strength of values in Ruby

Tags: ruby, jruby

I have a JSON with many records, for this question lets assume 100.  There are two keys, Change and Sign.  Change is something like 0.14 and Sign is one of two symbols "+" or "-".

For each one of the records, I would like to add two more keys "20 record up total" and "20 record down total".  Where these equaled the sum of the last 20 records where the sign was "+" and "-" respectively.

So, for "20-record up total" something like:

```
array.collect {|array| array['change']}
array.collect {|array| array['sign']} 
if sign = "+" then
#store change in uparray
#when uparray has 20 records add it up and create variable 20recorduptotal
```

Any help is appreciated.  Thanks a lot

I believe I need to use .each_cons(20) but of only the records with the applicable sign.

Comment: `Change is an integer (0.14)` -- that cannot be true.

Comment: I'm not sure if I described it correctly.  In the JSON, Change will be a number like 0.14, and Sign will be either a positive or negative sign.  Sorry for the confusion.  Thanks

Comment: What happens for the 40 or more records at the start of the list, which don't have 20 previous up/down records?

Comment: I assumed a nil value would result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update: here's something that might actually work :)

I've defined a "summing queue" that calculates the sum of the last 20 items added to it. Its `sum` returns `nil` if it has fewer than 20 items.

```
class SummingQueue
  def initialize(length = 20)
    @values = []
    @sum = 0
    @length = length
  end

  def <<(value)
    @values << value
    @sum += value
    @sum -= @values.shift if @values.length > @length
  end

  def sum
    return nil if @values.length < @length
    @sum
  end
end

queues = Hash.new {|hash, key| hash[key] = SummingQueue.new }

array.each do |item|
  queues[item["sign"]] << item["change"]
  item["last_20_ups"] = queues["+"].sum
  item["last_20_downs"] = queues["-"].sum
end
```

Note that the `last_20_ups` will include the current value (if applicable) - if you want it to be the last 20 values *not* including the current one, then move the `queues[...] << item[...]` line to the end of the `each` block.

Comment: Thanks again @Andy H.  I'm going to have to stare at this one for a while, but right now, I keep getting 'code'NilClass can't be coerced into Fixnum'code' at this line 'code'@sum += value'code'.  Earlier I said I assumed it would return nil, so maybe this is my fault.  But really, I'd like it to return "0", that is what I'll finally write back to the JSON if there aren't enough records to calculate the ups/downs total.  (and in case its relevent, this is how I'm iterating the variable back on each record:'code'list.each_with_index do |day, i|
  day['ups'] = last_20_ups(list, i)
end
'code'

Comment: That probably means that some of your changes are nil. Is that possible? Also, if you'd like it to return 0, you just have to change the `return nil if ...` to `return 0 if ...`

Comment: Thanks for both tips :)  Well, first I changed the `nil` to `return 0`.  And also checked to make sure I had no `nil` changes, and I don't.  Though I do have '0' for change, and in those cases the sign is "-".  Could it be for the nil that returns if there aren't 20 records to add up?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19816/discussion-between-andy-h-and-user1644609)